# Bamboo unable to find framework corresponding to the target framework moniker?

Tags: xamarin, mono, bamboo

I am trying to implement Bamboo into creating an IPA file or APK file using Xbuild but I am getting 1 warning and 1 error:

The warning is the following:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mono/4.6.2.7/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Unable to find framework corresponding to the target framework moniker '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78'. Framework assembly references will be resolved from the GAC, which might not be the intended behavior.
```

The error is this:

```
 /usr/local/Cellar/mono/4.6.2.7/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets: error : PCL Reference Assemblies not installed.
```

I am unsure why this is happening because when I open the project in Xamarin studio and build it, it will be successful, and when I run it the app is fully functional with no problems at all.  I have located the file location of the profile 78 in the version 4.5 and it exists, I have the latest installed version of Mono Development Kit (MDK).  How can it build correctly in Xamarin but not in Bamboo, is it do with how I locate the files?

I have also tried to create the APK file on the terminal but got the same error as well.  I have tried a lot of fixes like uninstalling mono and reinstalling, I added .NETPortable from windows to Mac but that didn't work, why can't my mac find the profile 78 it is located on my mac.

The file `/usr/local/Cellar/mono/4.6.2.7/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/microsoft.common.targets` seems to be looking for the `.NetPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=78` but I have that in this location: `Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.6.2/lib/mono/xbuild.frameworks/.NetPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78` and I have pasted the .NetPortable folder in multiple locations to try and fix this error. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Although I have not touched Bamboo for quite some time(3+ years), one thing I personally do is to ensure your `xbuild` command works like a charm in a local environment with a similar setup. Seeing that you tried to create an `.apk` through the terminal and got the same error sounds like an installation error. The `PCL Reference Assemblies` should be apart of the MDK(Linux ex: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#usage). Seeing that you have it installed, it sounds like a potential issue with file permissions of the Bamboo user account?

Comment: @JonDouglas It could be an installation error but it's not a permissions error because I have admin rights and could even use the bamboo account to try which can do anything but how could I fix the installation error I have tried reinstalling the MDK, any recommendations?

Comment: @JonDouglas You were basically correct I don't know why but it was something to do with the account that it was happening because I reinstalled xamarin studio and that didn't work, I added the .NetPortable folders from windows and that didn't work, then after ages of trying to fix that I added a different account reinstalled xamarin again, checked for updates and then added the folders from windows and then it worked.  If you add both your information and mine as the answer I will accept it as that's what helped me.

Comment: When creating the apk files for the /t:PackageForAndroid is that literally the command you type or do you need a package in your project to call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have not touched Bamboo for quite some time(3+ years), one thing I personally do is to ensure your `xbuild` command works like a charm in a local environment with a similar setup. Seeing that you tried to create an `.apk` through the terminal and got the same error sounds like an installation error. The `PCL Reference Assemblies` should be apart of the MDK on MacOS. Seeing that you have it installed, it sounds like a potential issue with file permissions of the Bamboo user account.

To create an `.apk` file, you need to use the `/t:PackageForAndroid` target against your Android project when invoking `xbuild`.

EX:

```
xbuild XamarinAndroidApplication.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /t:PackageForAndroid
```

You can also use the `SignAndroidPackage` target given the notes here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/build_process/#Build_Targets

```
xbuild XamarinAndroidApplication.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /t:SignAndroidPackage
```

If you wanted to use the `MSBuild` equivalents, it would look like this:

```
msbuild MyAndroidApp.sln
msbuild /t:SignAndroidPackage MyAndroidApp.csproj
```

Comment: I get the error Target named 'PackageForAndroid' not found in the project or 'Install' or 'SignAndroidPackage'  do you know why that is?

Comment: Are you running this against the `Android` .csproj?

Comment: no I can't it's in a project folder that has multiple .csproj that need packages etc so i have to use .sln

Comment: I was told that Xbuild now supported .sln files am I wrong?

Comment: `xbuild` has always been supported. I believe you mean `MSBuild` which is now better supported on MacOS.

The problem with providing a `.sln` is that the build system doesn't know what you want a final binary from. Thus if you give it a `.csproj`, it knows "This is an Android project and I can run the Sign/Packaging target against it as being told by you".

Comment: that's not really what I meant but if that is the case how can I create the apk using either xbuild or msbuild as if I use the .csproj I will get dependency references errors (51 to be exact)

Comment: You can see my `MSBuild` item above. Ideally you would want to re-build your whole application first and then individually call the `/t:SignAndroidPackage` target on the `.csproj`.

Comment: Before going into any further depth, I would highly advise that you open up a new question regarding these items as this is somewhat off-topic from the original question.

Comment: It wasn't me that built the project and it's a mobile app, I only have the application through bamboo and to rebuild it would take 6 months lol so I think I will try MSBuild instead